# Yii2 - generated password hash different every time

Tags: php, hash, yii2, passwords

I'm trying to use Yii's generatePasswordHash() function, but I get a different hash with the same password, every time.

```
$this->password = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($this->password);
```

Here 3 hashes created with the password "test":

```
$2y$13$wsvC4i8YMwKKHJ2K5iYRG.Z0KBetOh3BctVpJN5pVkXGOcW85hRkO ,
$2y$13$QfV2Qxlj4F5gUh1wIL2WUewoZ55CKYKevjRmRqrenxq8L5ym5xX9. ,
$2y$13$rDArvLa8hnpDGiiDdCs7be4iTsr2T3XMXmnapynuD1i1ekbz8zF4m
```

Anyone an idea what's happening?

EDIT:

When I try to verify with:

```
Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $this->password)
```

it returns false.

EDIT#2:
function looks like this:

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
}
```

$password is the input password and $this->password is the hash.

Strangely `password_verify($password, $this->password)` works, but Yii's verifier doesn't.

Comment: Try checking with `yii\helpers\VarDumper::dump()` right before `validatePassword()` call if the values of `$password` and `$this->password` are what you are expecting.

Comment: The hash is different each time because every time you are generating hash the random salt is generated. That salt is used when creating a hash and it's also added to the result string. Basically the structure of the result string is `$Algorithm$Options$SaltHash`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Already logged both values (debug) and accepted that I wouldn't get a conclusion. I'm now using the normal php function to verify.

Answer (score 2):

All hashes are correct. Because hash algorithms make different hashes for the same password. Where does the password variable come from in your code? It should be a password string not a hash.

```php
$hash = "hashed version";
$password = "string password";

if (Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $hash)){
   // password correct
}
```

Comment: @ChrisWeit you might be providing incorrect password the yii2 password validator does work correctly and generates a different has every time

Answer (score 0):

Adding to efendi's answer.

Getting a different hash each time Yii's generatePasswordHash() function is run is normal behavour.

Validating the password against the hash requires the 'salt' from the 'hash'.

The first 22 characters after '$2y$13$' in the hash is the salt.

The validatePassword($password, $hash) function gets the salt from the hash, hashes the $password using the salt which should get the same hash as the $hash if the password were to be correct.